# tkinter GUI doesn't appear?

Tags: python, tkinter

Small problem here, my code seem to be clean but the tkinter GUI doesn't appear ? Can seem to figure it out. The GUI / Code is for a report form type.

Thanks for your help in advance

```
from tkinter import *

class FicheDeSignalement(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        programme = Frame()
        programme.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        programme.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=5)
        programme.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=5)

        self.pages = {}
        for onePage in (StartProgram, InformationsPage):
            start_page = onePage(programme, self)
            self.pages[onePage] = start_page
            start_page.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_pages(StartProgram)

    def show_pages(self, cont):
        see_start_page = self.pages[cont]
        see_start_page.tkraise()


class StartProgram(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        label = Label(self, text="Fiche de Signalement", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        start_button = Button(self, text="Commencer", command=lambda: controller.see_page(InformationsPage))
        start_button.pack()


class InformationsPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)

        label = Label(self, text="Informations sur le suspect", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        person_suspected = Label(self, text="Prenom")
        person_suspected.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        first_name = Entry(self)
        first_name.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        person_suspected_2 = Label(self, text="Nom")
        person_suspected_2.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        last_name = Entry(self)
        last_name.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

        person_height = Label(self, text="Grandeur")
        person_height.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        size_height = Entry(self)
        size_height.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        person_weight = Label(self, text="Poids")
        person_weight.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        size_weight = Entry(self)
        size_weight.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

app = FicheDeSignalement()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: the indentation is broken in the code you posted.

Comment: yes I know the class indentation is wrong but it doesn't show anyway

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it doesn't show anyway", but it is showing incorrectly. The only thing we have to go on is the code as it appears in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to indentation errors and missing import statements and missing definition of `LARGE_FONT`, you have this problem:

```
label = Label(self, text="Informations sur le suspect")
label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

person_suspected = Label(self, text="Prenom")
person_suspected.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Both `label` and `person_suspected` share the same parent (`self`), but one uses `pack` and one uses `grid`. You can't use both of them with widgets that share a common parent. You must use only `grid` or only `pack`.

Comment: awesome ! I understand ! one or the other ! thanks alot